# Modesty according to custom?

Tags: tznius-modesty

Is modesty in Judaism somewhat allowed leeway according to custom? Most woman seem to show some parts of their body and they are somewhat considered modest.

Comment: By custom do you mean like based off of the times we live in and today’s standards?

Comment: Yes and by the country

Comment: To some extent. There are areas that are private no matter what the custom, and some areas that are custom dependent.

Comment: Idk on one hand the Torah is a living document and goes with the times, but on the other our rabbis explicitly say stuff like “hair and ankles elicit attraction and should therefore be covered” but we don’t know if we still need to listen to them because they said this in an extremely modest time but nowadays people walk around in much worse